# 2012 golf TDI brake bleeding with shared master cylinder

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, golf, brake-fluid, bleeding

just a quick question. I have a 2012 VW Golf TDI with a manual transmission. I was planning on flushing the brake system and from my research I noticed that my clutch and brakes both share the same master cylinder. So with that, is there a special procedure to flush the brake system or will it be the same process like doing it on a car with an automatic transmission?

Comment: Because the clutch and brake systems must operate independently, they cannot share a master cylinder. What they can do, however, is share a master cylinder _reservoir_. Underneath the reservoir, there will be two, separate, independent master cylinders.

Answer (score 1):

Should be the same as with an automatic. IF (big if) there is a bleeder nipple on the clutch slave cylinder and you have a power (or vacuum) bleeder, you can also flush out the clutch hydraulic fluid at the same time (do this last). If you're doing your brakes manually, you're probably better off just leaving the clutch line alone. Without a power bleeder you really run the risk of getting air in the clutch line and that would mess things up.